# Why is Boolean return type required?

Tags: java, return, boolean

I have a class `ShoppingCart` that uses `ItemOrder` objects.

```
public class ShoppingCart extends ArrayList<ItemOrder> {
```

I have a method that checks if an object already exsists in an array list, if so replace index with new object, if not add new object.

```
public boolean add(ItemOrder order){
    if (super.indexOf(order) != -1){      //ITEM ALREADY IN LIST, REPLACE
        super.remove(super.indexOf(order));
        super.set(super.indexOf(order), order);
    }
    else                                  //ITEM NOT IN LIST, ADD
        super.add(order);
    return true;                          //TO SATISFY RETURN TYPE
}
```

When I wrote the method, I didn't have a return type. I was getting an error that suggested I set the return type to void, so I did that. I then got another error, the return type had to be boolean. My only problem is that the method itself is not inherently(at least to me) a true/false return. All I need it to do is add/replace an object in an ArrayList, not return anything at all.

Why does this method require a boolean return type, and am I safe in simply throwing in `return true;`at the end, or should I actually have some use for it?

Comment: You're overriding List.add(), and make it do it something that doesn't respect the List.add() contract. Don't do that. Don't extend ArrayList. Instead, **use** a List as a field of the ShoppingCart. A ShoppingCart is not a list. It can use a list to store its elements, though.

Comment: Not your question but, if you do `super.remove(super.indexOf(order));` then what is the indexOf in the following statement `super.set(super.indexOf(order), order);` ?

Comment: To clarify: you are overriding the method because it has the same name and same parameter types as [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-).  You tried to give it a different return type, but Java does not look at the return type when deciding whether one method overrides another.

Comment: adding to @ScaryWombat, you are removing an element from the `List`, the `List` would now reorganize and you´d override another value in the `List`. There wouldn´t be a gap that you are filling, like i guess you are intending to do. Afterwards, if you add an already existing item, this implementation would leave you with one item less (if it would find the index).

Comment: @ScaryWombat , wow. I never actually did any test on it, just wrote it and thought it was strange. You're right though, if I remove the object from the list, then it has nothing to fill in. Damn it.

Comment: @KevinEsche Would you recommend using some sort of a temp  to transfer the information?

Comment: @JeffreyDilley if you really want to add or override and are actually needing what you are currently doing (inheriting from `ArrayList` and not a variable `List<ItemOrder> listName` like JBNizet said), than just remove the `super.remove` part.

Comment: If you want a list that doesn't allow duplicates, try using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). If retaining original insertion order is important, use a [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html). It's much faster than `List.indexOf()` logic, and you get full functionality for free. No override necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `add` method overrides the `ArrayList.add` which implements `Collection.add`

According to the javadoc `Collection.add`

> returns true if the collection changed as a result of the call

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)
and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)

Comment: That's what I get from learning how to code from youtube, lol. So do I need to include to Override annotation?? The code works fine w/o it. Also, am I safe simply throwing in return true?

Comment: No you'll be fine without the `@override` annotation, but it is good practice to include it for maintainability purposes. As for `return true;` then it could work for you now, but if your code is used by a class that expects a `ArrayList` and it does something when `add()` fails or returns `false` then that class would break. So in general when overriding you must respect the overriden method contract: return true if everything is okey-dokey, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you have the class below:

```
public class Example extends ArrayList<String>{

public boolean add(String order){
        if (super.indexOf(order) != -1){      //ITEM ALREADY IN LIST, REPLACE
            super.remove(super.indexOf(order));
            super.set(super.indexOf(order), order);
        }
        else                                  //ITEM NOT IN LIST, ADD
            super.add(order);
        return true;                          //TO SATISFY RETURN TYPE
    }

}
```

Adding the method `public boolean add(String order){..}` **you are actually overriding** the default method that it is contained in `ArrayList<String>` class.

Working with an `IDE` you can clearly see that you also need `@Override` annotation so it will be :

```
    @Override
    public boolean add(String order){
        if (super.indexOf(order) != -1){      //ITEM ALREADY IN LIST, REPLACE
            super.remove(super.indexOf(order));
            super.set(super.indexOf(order), order);
        }
        else                                  //ITEM NOT IN LIST, ADD
            super.add(order);
        return true;                          //TO SATISFY RETURN TYPE
    }
```

Also you can have a look at JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-)